# Thymeleaf variables scope global

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to define a Thymeleaf variable in the body tag so it is visible in all tags nested within the body.
But I want to assign a value in the form tag.

I tried:

```
<body style="padding-top: 65px;" th:with="isOwner=false">
    <form th:with="isOwner=true">
        <div th:text="${isOwner}"></div>
    </form>
    <div th:text="${isOwner}"></div>
</body>
```

Unfortunately this resulted in true false. Thus it seems that there are two variables.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to declare the same variable with another value in the form tag? Use a different variable name with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a variable using `th:with`. You are doing it once in `body` and again in `form`. Remove the `th:with` in the `form`

**Update**: These are local variables whose scope is between the tags.

Comment: But how do assign the value in the form? Is this even possible?

Comment: If you assign it in `form` its available only in that scope. Think of it as local variables in a function where function is everything between the start and end tag.